Why this does not add up to 0?
i was wondering, why the following sum does not add up to $0$. Consider the following sum of $S_n$ :
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n = S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + ... = \epsilon$$
And the specific elements looks like the following:
$$S_{2n} = (-1)q^n \text{ and } S_{2n+1} = (1)q^n$$
Where $q \in \mathbb{R}:\left| q \right| < 1$
Then the following sum could be considered:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)q^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1)q^n = (-1)\cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n + (1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n = -\frac{1}{1-q} + \frac{1}{1-q} = \frac{1-1}{1-q} =0$$
Or i thought of looking at this in some other way. Since we know $\lim_{N \to \infty}q^N \to 0$, then the sum could be written as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n = S_1 + S_2 + S_3 + ... + S_{N-2} + S_{N-1} + S_{N} + S_{N+1} + ... = \epsilon$$
Since we know that $q^N \to 0 $ as $N \to \infty$ the sum could be reduced to this form:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} S_n = \epsilon$$
And this could be written as:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} (-1)q^n + \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(1)q^n = (-1)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} q^n + (1)\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}q^n = -\frac{q^N-1}{q-1} + \frac{q^N-1}{q-1} = \frac{q^N-1-q^N+1}{q-1} = 0$$
Also my other approach was to check what happens if the $N-th$ therm does not cancel the one before it, so it remains some value $>0$. This will result in the following:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty S_n = S_1+S_2+S_3+...+S_{N-2}+S_{N-1}+S_{N} + S_{N+1} = ... = \epsilon$$
$$S_{N-1} = \epsilon$$
It does not really matter, if the $N-1-th$ term is odd or even parity because:
$$(-1)q^{N-1} = \epsilon \text{ and } (1)q^{N-1} = \epsilon$$
By multiplying with $q$ both sides i get the following:
$$(-1)q^N = q\epsilon\ \text{ and } (1)q^N = q\epsilon$$
And since i know, that $q^N$ will result in $0$, and $0 < q < 1$ meaning $q$ is not $0$, this implies, that $\epsilon = 0$.
My question is, where did i go wrong? I searched multiple sources, but did not really find any good explanation why this infinite sum would not add up to $0$. With my approach i always get, that unitl a certain $N$ the sum will add to some $\epsilon$ radius of $0$, and after that it will remain inside of that radius.

If you really have $q^n$ and $-q^n$ in the sum , they cancel out , but I guess you have another sum with minus sign for odd $n$ and plus sign for even $n$ or vice versa.

An infinite sum ∑ a_n converges if the sequence of partial sums P_n = ∑_{k=1}^n a_k converges to a finite limit L as n approaches infinity, i.e., lim_{n→∞} P_n = L. In your case indeed L=0 because partial sums are either zero or q^n, thus the limit exits and it equals zero. Just because some partial sums are bigger than zero it doesn't mean that the limit is bigger than zero.

Thanks for the answeres, my friend argued, that even though the limit exists and is indeed $0$, the sum does not add up to $0$, because of the alternating series property, and i was not really sure why. Also if you know any theories that has a proof that this kind of infinite sum add up to $0$ i would greatly appriciate the sources. :)

The claim “Since we know that $q_N\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$ the sum could be reduced to this form: [...]” is incorrect. For any fixed $N$, the number $q^N$ is nonzero (unless $q$ itself is zero, of course).

Yeah, but it in the sense that we can select an $N$ "big enough", such that all other $N+1,N+2...$ terms will "result in zero" e.g. we do not get out of the $\epsilon$ radius of $0$ implies, doesn't it? Sorry if i'm wrong on mathematical terminology...

"my friend argued, that even though the limit exists and is indeed 0, the sum does not add up to 0"  That's a contradiction.  The definition of the sum is that is the limit.  Plain and simple.  If a limit exists the sum exists and is whatever the limit is.  Period.

Of course you need to properly prove $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S_n = \lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^MS_n = 0$.  To do that note $\sum_{n=0}^{M} S_n = \begin{cases} 0&M\ odd\-q^{\frac M2}&M\ even\end{cases}$ so for any $\epsilon > 0$ if $M > 2\log_q \epsilon$ we have $|\sum_{n=0}^M S_n - 0| =\begin{cases} 0\|-q^{\frac M2}| \end{cases}\le q^{\frac M2} < q^{\log_q \epsilon} < \epsilon$.  The $ \lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^MS_n = 0$.  And thus the DEFINITION of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S_n = \lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^MS_n = 0$
